# how to custom form-control:valid pseudocode in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

i have a bootstrap form , want to show green tick in input box when both required and match my pattern ,
this is

```
.form-control.is-valid, .was-validated .form-control:valid {
    border-color: var(--bs-success);
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem);
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%23198754' d='M2.3 6.73.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem) center;
    background-size: calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) calc(0.75em + 0.375rem);
}
```

my complete code:
https://www.sololearn.com/compiler-playground/W9IK2TVx0Srn

how to i custom it in match my pattern?

Comment: Your question needs additional details. *want to show green tick in input box when both required* - both of what? Do you have just two input boxes, and both are required? *and match my pattern* - which pattern is that? Is it a RegEx pattern? Please post the relevant parts of your HTML code, so that we can better understand what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: my code: https://www.sololearn.com/compiler-playground/W9IK2TVx0Srn

Comment: Where does this constant `ippatern` actually get used?

Comment: `.was-validated .form-control:valid` will never apply. You have the `form-control` class on the `form` element, and some divs. While the form itself could be valid, it won't be a descendant of `.was-validated` (because that class is set on the form itself) - and div elements _can't_ be "valid" to begin with.

Comment: what is solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a couple of things, both in your HTML and your CSS.

First, add the class `.form-control-custom` to your `#GWTci` input element:

```
<input required class="form-control form-control-custom" type="text" name="" id="GWTci" class="form-inline">
```

Next, in your CSS, change the two following rulesets:

```
.form-control-custom.is-valid,
.was-validated .form-control-custom:valid {
    border-color: var(--bs-success);
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%23198754' d='M2.3 6.73.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem) center;
    background-size: calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) calc(0.75em + 0.375rem);
}
.form-control-custom.is-invalid,
.was-validated .form-control-custom:invalid {
    border-color: var(--bs-danger);
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 12 12' width='12' height='12' fill='none' stroke='%23dc3545'%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='6' r='4.5'/%3e%3cpath stroke-linejoin='round' d='M5.8 3.6h.4L6 6.5z'/%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='8.2' r='.6' fill='%23dc3545' stroke='none'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem) center;
    background-size: calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) calc(0.75em + 0.375rem);
}
```

to this

```
.was-validated .form-control-custom.valid {
    border-color: var(--bs-success) !important;
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem) !important;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%23198754' d='M2.3 6.73.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem) center !important;
    background-size: calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) !important;
}
.was-validated .form-control-custom.invalid {
    border-color: var(--bs-danger) !important;
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem) !important;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 12 12' width='12' height='12' fill='none' stroke='%23dc3545'%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='6' r='4.5'/%3e%3cpath stroke-linejoin='round' d='M5.8 3.6h.4L6 6.5z'/%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='8.2' r='.6' fill='%23dc3545' stroke='none'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem) center !important;
    background-size: calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) !important;
}
```

Note that:

- the `.form-control-custom.is-valid` was removed from both sets of rules
- instead of targeting the `.form-control-custom` class via the `:valid` / `:invalid` pseudoselectors, classes were used (`.valid` and `.invalid`, respectively), since they're added by your Javascript
- `!important` has been introduced as a way to enforce the rules. This isn't the best of solutions - you could achieve what you need by increasing the specificity (additional classes or attributes for your input(s), for example), and you could save yourself some trouble later on, if you ever have the need to override what you said was important at some point.

Your IP matching RegEx seems to be working correctly, and paired with the changes in the HTML and CSS will:

- add a green tick on form submit, if everything is fine
- remove the green tick and add an exclamation mark, if the input is invalid (regex check fails, or the required input is empty)

Comment: thanks,  there is any way to edit bootstrap source code?

Comment: Sure, you can host it on your webserver, instead of using a CDN. Once it's on your server, you can change it however you want. I'd advise against it, though.

Comment: how to changing the source code f bootstrap for this case(this post)?

Comment: What would you like to change? CSS, JS?

Comment: It does not differ with css or js. the goal is more important